# How to configure ASP.NET 6 HMR with UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer using webpack 5 and devserver 4

Tags: webpack-dev-server, webpack-5, .net-6.0

I successfully configured ASP.NET5 with Webpack4 to use HMR previously. Now, I tried to upgrade all to new versions and I couldn't make the HMR work at all.

**The problem is:** when I start (debug) the ASP.NET web app it shows me a '/ not found' page. It looks like the UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer redirects all requests to the Webpack DevServer which has no index.html at all because I just want to use it to provide HMR functionality for the ASP.NET site.

Here are all version changes:

- net5.0 > **net6.0**
- webpack: v4.43.0 > **v5.64.4**
- webpack-cli v3.3.12 > **v4.9.1**
- webpack-dev-server v3.11.0 > **v4.6.0**

The ASP.NET code is the same:

```
app.UseSpa(spa =>
{
     spa.UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer("http://localhost:8888");
});
```

The ASP.NET web site url is: https://localhost:44331

The DevServer configuration changed because there are lot of changes between v3 and v4 (https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/blob/master/migration-v4.md).

This is the previous (which was **working**) devServer config:

```
 devServer: {            
    compress: true,
    contentBase: false, 
    hot: true,            
    port: 8888,
    public: 'https://localhost:44331',
    publicPath: '/dist', //this is a subfolder under the wwwroot
    serveIndex: false,
 },
```

This is the new (which is **not working**) devServer config:

```
devServer: {
    hot: true,
    port: 8888,
    host: 'localhost',
    client: {
        webSocketURL: 'https://localhost:44331', //V3: devServer.public
    },
    devMiddleware: {
        publicPath: '/dist', //V3: devServer.publicPath
    },
    static: false //V3 ?
}
```

I'm not sure about the 'static' property (the contentBase was false previously) but I don't really think that can cause the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this I think?

```
devMiddleware: {
  index: false, // If false (but not undefined), the server will not respond to requests to the root URL.
  publicPath: '/dist'
},
```